# Django - Name Error when views call model's method

Tags: django, methods, nameerror

I am a newbie in Django. I have defined the models and a method

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Practice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Doctor(models.Model):
    specialisation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    practice = models.ForeignKey(Practice, related_name='doctor',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name ='doctor', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    selected = models.BooleanField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.specialisation

    def get_list_doctors(self):
        all_doctors = User.objects.exclude(pk=1).filter(doctor__isnull=False)
        all_doctors_names = all_doctors.values_list('last_name', 'first_name')
        return all_doctors_names

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='patient', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    practice = models.ForeignKey(Practice, related_name='patient',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    primary_doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, related_name='patient',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)


class Appointment(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, related_name='appointment',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    practice = models.ForeignKey(Practice, related_name='appointment',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name='appointment',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

This is my view

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ('You Have Been Logged In!'))

            doctor_list = get_list_doctors()
            context = { 'doctor_name': doctor_list}
            return render(request, 'homeunimed.html', context)
```

I am trying to use the method in the view. The reason for defining it in the model is so that I can reuse.

```
NameError at /
name 'get_list_doctors' is not defined
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'get_list_doctors' is not defined
Exception Location: /Users/vinoojacob/Django/my_app/authenticate/views.py in login_user, line 27
Python Executable:  /Users/vinoojacob/Django/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['/Users/vinoojacob/Django/my_app',
 '/Users/vinoojacob/Django/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/vinoojacob/Django/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/vinoojacob/Django/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/Shared/anaconda3/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/vinoojacob/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

However, I get this error. Any pointers to what is wrong. I thought you could access any methods defined in the model as long as the model is imported. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The get_list_doctors is belonging to the model class. So you can only call it on a model instance of Doctor.

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved it now calling on model instance of Doctor.

Comment: Just one comment: as you do not use the instance in your method, consider making this method a staticmethod by putting the deocrator @classmethod before the method and remove the self parameter. This will not change the functionality but would be the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote you can access it via model. So decorate your method with @staticmethod, leave out self as argument and call it this way `doctor_list = Doctor.get_list_doctors()`.

```
@staticmethod
def get_list_doctors():
    all_doctors = User.objects.exclude(pk=1).filter(doctor__isnull=False)
    all_doctors_names = all_doctors.values_list('last_name', 'first_name')
    return all_doctors_names
```

Comment: Thank you! I think an instance is required, does not seem to work directly on model.

Comment: @VinooPJacob Please see the edited answer. I would suggest not to call your method on object instance, since than you have to have an instance first. Your method returns all the doctors, so it is more universal to call it on Doctor model. This way you will be able to call it in any view, even in the views not containing the instance of a doctor.

Comment: Thank you!! I don't need an instance, so makes lot of sense to make it static.

Comment: @VinooPJacob Accepting the answer as correct would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The function `get_list_doctors(self)` is pretty useless and exclude a user hardcoding its pk. This is pretty bad.

A couple of suggestions:

1) Change the line in Doctor

```
 name = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name ='doctor', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

With:

```
user = models. OneToOneField(User, related_name ='doctor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The relation is a user and if the user is gone, then you must remove the Doctor too. And also, the relation is one to one!

2) You can get the list of the doctor very easily in your view

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ('You Have Been Logged In!'))
            doctors_list = Doctor.objects.exclude(user=user)
            context = { 'doctors_list': doctors_list}
            return render(request, 'homeunimed.html', context)
```

In your template, you can access the name of the doctors through the user (this is a very naive example)

```
{% for doctor in doctors_list %}
     First name: {{ doctor.user.first_name }}
     Last name: {{ doctor.user.last_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will add CASCADE on delete, will keep it tidy and not have orphans! On your second suggestion, I am filtering (pk=1), just to remove 'admin' user from the list, not the logged-in-user. I can now see it is not an elegant way to do it, will rather have the flag set correctly in the data so that admin is filtered out rather than having to do it in the code. Good catch though.

Comment: You can easily get all the not admin users: `User.objects.all().exclude(is_superuser=True)`

Comment: Vote the answer if you’re satisfied